# list of user-defined functions in R workspace

Tags: r, function

In R there are user-defined functions that are different than those in a library.

How do I get a list of only those functions?

I know there is `ls()` but it gives all objects.
I find that `class(x)` can say "function" if "x" is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `lsf.str` to return the functions created in the global env

```
lsf.str()
```

If we want to just get the names of the functions without the attributes

```
c(lsf.str())
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  How did you find this? Given your hint I used ?? on lsf, and it says DescTools has some wrappers for lsf.str. Nice.

Comment: @EngrStudent thanks.  I checked `?ls`, where there is a link for `?ls.str` and in the link there is `lsf.str` as well